How to get user profile photo using graph api in ASP.NET Core 8 MVC
I'm utilizing ASP.NET Core 8 MVC for my project. My current task involves retrieving a user's profile photo from Azure Active Directory using the Microsoft Graph API.
To accomplish this, I've initially set up a basic ASP.NET Core 8 MVC project and successfully configured Azure AD authentication. Now, I'm seeking guidance on how to integrate the Graph API into my project to fetch and display user profile photos.

Does the answer useful to you ?

Initially, register one Entra ID application and grant User.Read.All permission of Application type as below:

To get user profile photo using Graph API in ASP.NET Core 8 MVC, modify your code referring below sample files:
HomeController.cs:
using System.Web.Mvc;
using Azure.Identity;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Graph;
using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq;

public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
    {
        var scopes = new[] { "https://graph.microsoft.com/.default" };
        var tenantId = "tenantId";
        var clientId = "appId";
        var clientSecret = "secret";

        var options = new TokenCredentialOptions
        {
            AuthorityHost = AzureAuthorityHosts.AzurePublicCloud,
        };

        var clientSecretCredential = new ClientSecretCredential(tenantId, clientId, clientSecret, options);

        var graphClient = new GraphServiceClient(clientSecretCredential, scopes);

        try
        {
            var user = await graphClient.Users["userId"].GetAsync();
            ViewBag.Me = user;

            // Get the user's photo
            var photoStream = await graphClient.Users["userId"].Photo.Content.GetAsync();
            if (photoStream != null)
            {
                using (var memoryStream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    await photoStream.CopyToAsync(memoryStream);
                    ViewBag.Photo = Convert.ToBase64String(memoryStream.ToArray());
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception exception)
        {
            ViewBag.Error = $"{exception.GetType().FullName}: {exception.Message}";
        }

        return View();
    }
}

Index.cshtml:
@using Newtonsoft.Json.Linq
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "User Profile fetched from MS Graph";
    Layout = "~/Views/Shared/_Layout.cshtml";
}

<br />
<br />
<h1>User's Profile</h1>

<table class="table table-striped table-condensed" style="font-family: monospace" border="1">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>
                Profile picture
            </th>
            <th>
                @{
                    if (ViewBag.Photo != null)
                    {
                        <img style="margin: 5px 0; width: 150px" src="data:image/jpeg;base64, @ViewBag.Photo" />
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        <p>No Pic available for this user. Upload a pic for this user in the Azure portal</p>
                    }
                }
            </th>
            <th></th>
        </tr>
        @{
            var user = ViewBag.Me as Microsoft.Graph.Models.User;
            if (user != null)
            {
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        ID
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @user.Id
                    </th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        Display Name
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @user.DisplayName
                    </th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        Mail
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @user.Mail
                    </th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <th>
                        UserPrincipalName
                    </th>
                    <th>
                        @user.UserPrincipalName
                    </th>
                    <th></th>
                </tr>
            }
        }
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    </tbody>
</table>

OUTPUT:

